# strong-pm Cannot find module "--cluster=CPU"

Tags: node.js, strongloop

I'm new to strong-pm.  I have a offsite contractor that changed a configuration now our strong-pm service is not running

Getting the following exception, I can manage to change the cluster value from CPU to 1 or 2 with the following command but it looks like the parameters to the node process isn't getting passed correctly and it's thinking '--cluster=CPU' is a module.

```
slc ctl -C http://user:pass@host set-size notes 2
```

> Error: Cannot find module '/var/lib/strong-pm/svc/1/work/1243100a8374d67ec4f638539a27d7a8e232fee8.1487911131627/--cluster=CPU'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
>       at Object. (/usr/lib/node_modules/strong-pm/node_modules/strong-supervisor/bin/sl-run.js:77:19)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
>       at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)

Answer (score 0):

Contractor accidentally set an environment variable and was able to unset the value with the following command.

`slc ctl -C http://… env-unset <SRV> ENV_VAR`